# bootstrap cakephp help needed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

i am creating a form with cakephp2 and bootstrap everything is working fine but im stuck in little confusion and i cant fix this kindly any bootstrap or cake expert help me thanks,

[image: Screnshot]

Check this envelop its stretching upwards

here is my code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
        </span>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('email',
            array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'type' => 'email',
                'placeholder' => 'Enter Email'
            )
        ); ?>
    </div>
    <!--<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required="required" /></div>-->
</div>
```

Comment: try `'label' => false` in the `array(`. This prevent to display the label

Comment: eg `<?php echo $this->Form->input('email',
            array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'type' => 'email',
                'placeholder' => 'Enter Email',
                'label' => false
            )
        ); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Pass the argument `'label' => false` will prevent to display the label

Use

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('email',
            array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'type' => 'email',
                'placeholder' => 'Enter Email',
    'label' => false
            )
        ); ?>
```

Comment: While disabling the label will work, possible validation error messages will break the layout again in a similar way, so I'd also suggest to use the `before` and `after` [**options**](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options) to wrap the input in the bootstrap `.input-group` div.

Answer (score -1):

You should use label false in your code.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
        </span>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('email',
            array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'type' => 'email',
                'label'=>false,
                'placeholder' => 'Enter Email'
            )
        ); ?>
    </div>
    <!--<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required="required" /></div>-->
</div>
```